# How to call a function stored in a Unit?

Tags: delphi, pascal

I created a new unit because there are functions that I need to call from all forms and I placed the unit name in the *uses* list.

I don't get any error at design time but when I try to start the application I get [DCC Error] UnitForm1.pas(64): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'TaskBarHeight'

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I think it has something to do with binding, otherwise the error would already occur during compilation. We'd need to see more code (how the identifier is declared etc.)

Comment: @travelboy: emurad is probably talking about a compile-time error, and not a run-time error. (Design-time is something else.)

Comment: @Andreas: if so, I misunderstood that. But then it should be easy to fix.

Comment: Yes, that's correct: compile error - sorry I've been using interpreters for a longtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is `TaskBarHeight` declared in the `interface` section of the unit?

```
unit Unit4;

interface

uses Windows;

procedure HighBeep;

function Sum(const A, B: integer): integer;

const
  alpha = 10;

implementation

const
  beta = 20;

procedure HighBeep;
begin
  Beep(800, 500);
end;

procedure LowBeep;
begin
  Beep(400, 500);
end;

function Sum(const A, B: integer): integer;
begin
  result := A + B;
end;

end.
```

In the above example, only the function `HighBeep` is visible in other units. Also, only the constant `alpha` is. The function `sum` is also visible.

Comment: It's a function, not procedure. It returns value. What's the syntax?

Comment: it does not matter if it is a procedure or a function, just depends where it is defined. If it is defined in the interface section it will be visible to other units, otherwise it is only visible to that unit only.